# How can I replace _ with - in my URL in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting, seo

I have my controller names set up as "My_Controller". I'm looking for a way to change my URL from **www.mysite.com/My_Controller/My_Action**
    to   **www.mysite.com/my-controller/my-action/**.

Is there anyway to do this without using a URL re-writer extension? If so, how?

Comment: Why can't you rename your controller ?

Comment: I don't believe dashes are allowed when naming a controller.

Comment: I hadn't heard that but then again I'd never tried !

Comment: Well, I just tried it and it worked perfectly well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a routehandler.

```
public class HyphenatedRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
        try
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
        }
        catch { }
        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

..and add it to your route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
        ).RouteHandler = new HyphenatedRouteHandler();
```

This will mean that, whenever you have a controller named "Example_Controller" with an action called "Example_Action", you will be able to call it with /example-controller/example-action

Comment: Thanks for the input. Let me give that a try!

Comment: For what it's worth, I just created a new Mvc3 website and specifically named the controller with an Underscore in the name and it worked just fine. Only thing being creating a controller called my_controller with an action called index yielded a url of localhost:87821/My_/index